# Formula for juxtaposition of paths defined by equivalence classes?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am interested in the equations for the juxtaposition of two paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I have the following equivalence relation;
\begin{equation}
(x,y) \sim (x',y') \iff x-x', q-q' \in \{0,1\}
\end{equation}
on the space $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$. I believe this glues opposite sides of the square together to create a torus.
The question I have is:

Let $x_0 ∈ X/ ∼$ denote the point $x_0 = [(0, 0)]$. Define paths $\alpha, \beta: [0, 1] → X/ ∼$ by the
rules $\alpha(t) = [(t, 0)] \; \text{and} \; \beta(t) = [(0, t)]$ for $t ∈ [0, 1]$. Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ both start and
end at $x_0$.
Find the formula for $\alpha * \beta$ and $\beta * \alpha$, the juxtaposition of these paths.

I am very stuck on where to begin with this. I am a little confused by seeing paths defined by equivalence classes as I haven't seen this before, but think the path $\alpha$ starts at $x_0$ and loops around the inside ring of the torus (ie. the hole of a donut) and $\beta$ starts at $x_0$ and loops from the hole around to the outer edge. I really don't know where to begin so any help or discussion would be appreciated.

Comment: Your equivalence relation must have a sort of typo: note that $(x-x',q-q')$ is a tuple and couldn't possibly be in the set $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek thanks for pointing that out, I have amended now.

Comment: @user383838 the formula for path composition remains the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition I'm not sure what other formula you are looking for? The only thing that you need to check is that this formula is valid, i.e. that ending of $\alpha$ is beginning of $\beta$ and vice versa. This is true over torus, not true over $[0,1]\times [0,1]$.

Comment: @freakish I think this might be my question - I'm not sure what I am being asked for.  The question notes that both paths are loop with the same start/endpoint, so think this is given. Just not sure if there is some explicit formula they are looking for other than just writing out the definition of juxtaposition and plugging the paths in?

Comment: So you're asking "is it asking for explicit formula depending on $x$ and $t$ or just illustration (i.e. describe the path, where is goes along)?" I would choose the former one since an explicit expression with two pieces describing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ also helps to illustrate its shape. Just like what freakish has said, since then you need to specify what kind of formula you're looking for, once you've done that, the expression should be clear because you must know how to combine two paths together, right?

Comment: I think you want the formula appeared in the hyperlink provided by freakish, its enough for describing the combined path, because you've already written the two paths explicitly, hence it should be straight forward. I'm not sure if these two comments answer your question.